# How can I send a file and a string to my backend C# from JQuery Ajax?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

My UI has one input for uploading file and one input for the file's name.

I want to get both file and its name from user at the same ajax request and upload the file with the gotten name to my server.

**the question is how can I get both file (binary) and the file's name from user at the same request ?**

here is my try but results in 400 error.

Function in C#:

```
public IActionResult UploadImage(IFormFile upload, string fileWithName)
    {
      //some code here
    }
```

and here is my ajax:

```
$("#startUploading").on("click",function() {

            var fileInput = $.trim($("#myfile").val());

            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('upload', $('#myfile')[0].files[0]);
            formData.append('pathWithName', $("#fileAddressUploadTo").val());

            $.ajax({
                url: apiUrl+'/api/V1/Servers/UploadImage',
                type: 'POST',
                data: formData,
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token'));
                },
                cache: false,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false
            });

           
});
```

Comment: `"mimeType": "multipart/form-data"` ?

Comment: set name of your inputs as c# names and in your ajax use : data = new FormData($frm[0])

Comment: your js set `formData.append('pathWithName',` and your api set input parameter `string fileWithName`, but it also won't lead to 400

Answer (score 4, accepted):

400 error means bad request, but per my test I found it worked for me. So I'm afraid the issue in your code may relate to `$('#myfile')[0].files[0]`, see my code below

```
<div>
    <input type="file" id="uploadFile" />
    <button id="btn4">upload</button>
</div>

$("#btn4").click(function(){
    var form = new FormData();
    var temp = $('#uploadFile').prop('files');
    form.append("file",temp[0]);
    form.append("name","myFile");
    console.log(form);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://localhost:44321/hello/upload',
        type: 'POST',
        data: form,
        cache:false,
        contentType:false,//stop jquery auto convert form type to default x-www-form-urlencoded
        processData:false,
        success: function (d) {
            alert(d)
        }
    });
});


public string upload(IFormFile file, string name) { 
    return "hello";
}
```

[image]